# What is the difference between Verilog ! and ~?

Tags: verilog, boolean-logic, modelsim

So it ended up that the bug that had kept me on for days, was a section of code that should have evaluated to False evaluating to True. My initial code went something like:

```
if(~x && ~y) begin
    //do stuff
end
```

i.e. If x is NOT ONE and y is NOT ONE then do stuff. Stepping through the debugger, I realized even though x was 1 the expression in the if-statement still resulted into TRUE and the subsequent code was executed.

However, when I changed the statement to:

```
if(x == 0 && y == 0) begin
//do stuff
end
```

and also tried:

```
if(!x && !y) begin
//do stuff
end
```

the code within the if-statement was not evaluated which was the expected behaviour. I understand that ~ is a bitwise negation and ! a logical negation, but shouldn't (~x && ~y) and (!x && !y) evaluate to the same thing? I'm afraid the codebase is too large, so I can't paste it here, but this was the only alteration I made to make the code to work as I intended. Thanks.

---

In response, to one of the comments below, I have created a test-case to test this behaviour:

```
`timescale 10ns/1ns

module test_negation();
        integer x, y;

    initial begin
        x = 1; y = 0;

        if(~x && ~y) begin
            $display("%s", "First case executed");
        end

        if(!x && !y) begin
            $display("%s", "Second case executed");
        end

        if(x == 0 && y == 0) begin
            $display("%s", "Third case executed");
        end
    end endmodule
```

And strangely enough, "First case executed" is printed to confirm the original behaviour I observed.

Comment: guessing, but wouldn't bitwise negation would be something like `~0xAA = 0x55`, v.s. `!0xAA` being the equivalent of "0xAA is not zero, so evaluate to true".

Comment: @Marc B Yeah, that's an important difference. However in this case, both x and y are 1 bit long. If x is "1", I'd expect a bitwise negation ~x to be "0"..

Comment: One bit long? How odd. Can you make a test project to display the values of `x`, `!x`, `~x`, `y`, `!y`, `~y`, and `(~x && ~y)` and `(!x && !y)`?

Answer (score 14):

`~` is a bit-wise operator and returns the invert of the argument.

`!` is a logical operator and returns a single bit.

Example:

```
reg [7:0] bit_wise, logic_op;
initial begin
  bit_wise = ~8'hA1; // bit_wise == 8'h5E
  logic_op = !8'hA1; // logic_op == 8'b00
  $display("bit_wise:%h logic_op:%h", bit_wise, logic_op); // bit_wise:5e logic_op:00
end
```

For your example:

```
if(~x && ~y) begin
    //do stuff
end
```

Is effectively the same as:

```
if(x!='1 && y!='1) begin // '1 means the with of x all 1s and the with of y all 1s
    //do stuff
end
```

Generally the best coding style is to use logical operators inside if statements. Only use bit-wise operators with data assignment manipulations.

Comment: FYI - The `'1` syntax is not valid Verilog syntax. This construct was introduced in SystemVerilog.

Comment: Not knowing the widths of `x` and `y`, I decided using SystemVeilog syntax and placed a note explain what `'1` is intended for. Since the release of IEEE Std 1800-2009, Verilog and SystemVerilog are one and the same <http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=5354133>. (Mentioned in the abstract, maybe someone else can find a better citation.)

Comment: That use of ~ in the if statement is not very clear. I would always use ~ with a comparison. Also my simulator does not think Verilog and SystemVerilog are the same thing. Verilog is often used to refer to the 1995 or 2001 specs before SystemVerilog it makes a big difference to those using older tools.

Answer (score 9):

I see. The variable "x" in the above code was a Verilog integer (`integer x;`). However, an *integer* variable is represented by Verilog as a 32-bit integer number. So even though x was "1" as I had observed, ~x will not result in "0" but in "11111111111111111111111111111110"! And so it's no surprise that the First Case was executed. My fault. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. The lesson is to use the `reg` & `wire` types in classic Verilog, or the `bit` & `logic` types in modern Verilog, and size your signals appropriately. (Be warned, those types aren't equivalent)

Comment: According to IEEE Std 1364, an `integer` may be implemented as larger than 32 bits.  IEEE Std 1800 (SystemVerilog) fixes the width to 32 bits.