# Ring Counter in Verilog

Tags: verilog, circuit, digital-logic, iverilog

I need to modify this ring counter to shift from the most to least significant bit and then resets back to the most significant bit. The output should look like this:

```
100000 
010000 
001000 
000100  
000010 
000001 
100000
```

**Ring Counter**

```
module ringcounter(clk, rst, count);  
    input clk, rst; 
    output [5:0] count; 
    wire clk, rst; 
    reg [5:0] count = 6'b1;  
    // Respond to the positive-going pulse edge     
    always @ ( posedge clk ) 
        begin   
        if ( ~rst )   
            begin     
            count <= count << 1;    
            count[0] <= count[5];   
        end 
    end  
    // Respond to the positive-going reset signal 
    always @ ( posedge rst ) 
    begin   
        count <= 6'b1; 
    end  
endmodule
```

**Ring Counter Testbench**

```
module ringcounter_tb();  
    reg clk = 0, rst = 0; 
    wire [5:0] count;  
    always #1 clk = !clk; // Create a clock pulse  

    initial begin   
    $monitor("At time %4t, count = %b", $time, count );  
        #20 rst = 1;   
        #1  rst = 0;
        #20 $finish; 
    end  

    ringcounter cntr01 ( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .count(count) );  
endmodule
```

I am still very new to digital logic, so please bear with me. I am just a little confused as to how I could modify this ring-counter. Any kind of help, or explanation as to how exactly this would work, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear here. But a couple of things to be **modified**.

Firstly, **never use same variable** in **two different** `always` blocks. Just add `rst` to the **sensitivity list**. something like follows:

```
// sensitive to clock and reset both
always @ ( posedge clk, posedge rst )
        begin   
        if ( ~rst )   
            begin     
            count <= count << 1;    
            count[0] <= count[5];   
        end 
          else 
            count <= 8'b1;
    end
```

Using **edge sensitive** `always` blocks results in **flip-flop creation**. If this is done in *two* different blocks, then **synthesis issues** shall occur. This can be visualized by the logic you want in terms of gates and registers.

Also, during the clock generation, use of **bitwise** negation is recommended (`~`).

The `!` symbol represents **boolean or logical negation**. While `~` symbol represents **bitwise negation**.

```
// Replace this
always #1 clk = !clk;
// With this
always #1 clk = ~clk;
```

Applying `rst` after `20ns` and terminating the simulation after `20ns` shall not be what you want. You may want to use `#200 $finish;` instead.

These were some of the points I wanted to make clear. I simulated the code at [EDAPlayground here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/HPs), maybe you want to see the **waveforms**, which seems to be according to the one described in question.

More guidelines about synthesis can be obtained from [this PDF](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/sp07/Lectures/08-DesignSynthesisx6.pdf).

Refer [Always block hardware implementation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29553/how-are-verilog-always-statements-implemented-in-hardware) and [Difference in negation operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424726/what-is-the-difference-between-verilog-and) links for further information.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the great explanations. The resources I was given for class were not very good. So this helps a lot. As for what I need to accomplish, right now it is shifting from least significant bit to the most significant and I need to switch that. From most to least significant bit. I have a feeling it is simpler than I am making it out to be, but as I mentioned in my post, I am still a very new with digital logic.

Comment: We weren't given a textbook for class either, otherwise I'd look this up. Thank you though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Mention not.. :) This code just performs circular shifting of `count[5]` (MSB) to `count[0]` (LSB). And shifting other bits by `<<` operator. You can also perform the other side shifting using `>>` operator and `count[5]<=count[0]`. Just for your information.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I knew it was something simpler than I was making it out to be. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/vividvilla/4605985

This should work, It contains both the test bench as well as the output for the program :)