# Difference between & and && in conditional block in SystemVerilog

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog

Here are two programs in SystemVerilog.

```
module tb_1;    
  
  logic [3:0] a = 4'b1101;
  logic [3:0] b = 4'b1011;
  
  initial begin
    if (a&b)
      $display ("TRUE"); 
    else
      $display ("FALSE"); 
  end
endmodule

module tb_2;    
  
  logic [3:0] a = 4'b1101;
  logic [3:0] b = 4'b1011;
  
  initial begin
    if (a&&b)
      $display ("TRUE"); 
    else
      $display ("FALSE"); 
  end
  
endmodule
```

The only difference between the two is that, in the first case & is used and in the second case && is used. Both of them run. Both of them give the same result as TRUE.

How do we know whether to use & or &&? I am sure that they do not mean the same thing. One of them is called bit-wise AND while the other is called logical AND.

I was expecting this to give different result since bit-wise AND gives 1001 as result which has zeros in it. And how does logical AND work on multi-bit values (rather than a C boolean type), I do not know.

Comment: When using `&&`, you are evaluating boolean operands (and it is short-circuiting, will only evaluate what is needed to determine a result). When you use `&`, you are evaluating numeric operands (and it is _not_ short-circuiting, will evaluate _all_ operands). When you do `if (result)`, you coerce your numeric result into a boolean (and thus non-zeros are `true`).

Comment: Sorry, actually I run the two programs one at a time. This means that I either run tb_1 or tb_2 but not both. In actuality I have a single program in edaplayground called tb and I just change between & and && to rerun the code.

Answer (score -1):

SystemVerilog takes the *true* branch when the `if` condition is known to be non-zero. It takes the *false* branch when the condition is known to be zero or unknown.

If you are looking at expressions to be *true* or *false* results, you most likely want logical operators. The logical and relational operators all return 1'b1 for true and 1'b0 for false.

But it's possible to use a combination of logical and bitwise operators in the same expression—it really depends on the functionality you are trying to achieve. Take a look at [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424726/what-is-the-difference-between-verilog-and)

Answer (score -1):

> I was expecting this to give different result since bit-wise AND gives 1001 as result which has zeros in it.

I think you are mixing the **bitwise AND operator** `a & b` and the **reduction unary AND operator** `&x`.

`a & b` is indeed `4'b1001`. However, `4'b1001` is a 4-bit integer and will NOT automatically AND its bits together to form a 1-bit "boolean" value `0` inside `if` expression. Instead, Systemverilog treats all non-zero integer values as TRUE, as deplicted in dave_59's answer.

If you do intend to bitwse-AND the `4'b1001` into `1'b0`, you need to add an **reduction unary AND operator** (`&x`) on it:

```
&( a & b )
```